# Property 'formSubmitted' does not exist on type 'ContactComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I used ngClass for a form so I can color it depending on if the field is valid or not, when i build it locally for testing (debug build) the webpage works correctly, form inputs get colored. 
If I try to publish the website using FTP, it will fail on build (release build). I am building the website from Visual Studio, because I am working on ASP + Angular, but my question with asp tag did not get any luck.

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}">
// here come form inputs which all highlight correctly on local test build (I can post them if neccessary)
</form>
```

.ts file imports

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

.ts code regarding the form

```
 emailForm: FormGroup;
  email: Email;
  emailString: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      senderName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
      senderEmail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      senderSubject: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
      senderMessage: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
    });
  }
```

The exact error I am getting while publishing is: ERROR in src\app\contact\contact.component.html(4,63): : Property 'formSubmitted' does not exist on type 'ContactComponent'. Did you mean 'onFormSubmit'?

Comment: You might have not define formSubmitted in your component , please share the code of component.

Comment: I did not, I never found an example where they did. Would "declare var form-submitted: any" work?

Comment: @Impavid no. `[ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}` means: "go look at the value of the property formSubmitted of the component. If it's truthy, add the CSS class form-submitted". Why do you expect this to be correct if you never defined any `formSubmitted` property in the component. Where do you expect this property to come from if you don't define it yourself?

Comment: JB, this is my first angular website, I expected it to work because it worked on debug build, it only crashed while building it for release. Anyway, I have solved it with help of ngfelixl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the property `formSubmitted` publically in your component class.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class ContactComponent {
  formSubmitted = false;
  // ...
}
```

When the user submits the form the function `onFormSubmit()` is executed. Implement this function in your component class above and set the `formSubmitted` property to `true` here.

```
onFormSubmit() {
  this.formSubmitted = true;
  // ...
}
```

and in your template you can apply the class by

```html
<form [class.form-submitted]="formSubmitted">
```

Comment: I suggest an edit. Considering I do not need to set the value of formSubmitted manually, I only added `formSubmitted: boolean;` and it works. I haven't even changed my html. Thank you for your answer.